# Filtro por Tags problema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtro

Estoy haciendo un test, donde creé todo dentro de App.js. El problema es que al setear tags como una propiedad desde setStudent (se que no se debe hacer pero no me quedo otra), no puedo filtrar busqueda por tags. Como deberia setear tags para que al agregarlo como propiedad , pueda hacer una busqueda por filtro del mismo?

```
const [search,setSearch]=useState("")
const [searchByTag,setSearchByTag]=useState("")
const [students,setStudents]=useState([])
const [filteredData,setFilteredData]=useState([])
const [tags,setTags]=useState({})**

const addTags = (event,id) =>{
if(event.target.value !== "") {
 setTags({...tags,[id]:[...(tags[id] || []),event.target.value]});
 event.target.value = "";
}  
}

useEffect(()=>{
getApi();
},[]);
const getApi = async () =>{
const data = await fetch('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
const students = await data.json()
setStudents(students.students.map(({grades,...students})=>
({...students,grades,tag:tags,gradedAverage:grades.reduce((acc ,item)=>acc + 1*item,0)/grades.length})))**      
};
console.log(students)

useEffect(()=>{
setFilteredData(
 students.filter((tags)=>`${tags}`.toLowerCase().includes(searchByTag.toLowerCase())),
)
},[setSearchByTag,students])**


       <TextField onChange={(e)=>{setSearchByTag(e.target.value)}}  id="standard-search2"  label="Search by tags" type="search" style={{width:'100%'}}/>
```

Comment: javascript en REact JS

Answer (score 1):

Sea como sea que guardes el objeto, la forma de agregar la propiedad de manera de poder filtrarlo, debería ser algo asi:

```
function setTags(tags, id){// <-- tags es un array de strings  

obj.students = obj.students.map(e=>{

  if(+e.id === id){

    if("tags" in e){

        
      e.tags.push(...tags);// <-- si ya hay tags los agregamos 

    }else{

        e.tags = tags;

    }

  }
  
  return e;

})    

}
```

Para filtrar, debería ser algo como:

```
function filtrar_pot_tag(tag){// <-- buscamos un string como tag

    return obj.students.filter(e=>{
  
    if("tags" in e){// <-- si tiene algún tag lo buscamos

        return e.tags.some(e2=>e2.includes(tag));

    }else{
        return false;
    }
  
  })

}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por el apoyo. Me tira varios errores...primero obj no esta definido...asi que no se por que lo deberia cambiar.
Ademas, deberia usar el filtar_por_tag en vez del searchByTag en la linea
<TextField onChange={(e)=>{setSearchByTag(e.target.value)}}  id="standard-search2"  label="Search by tags" type="search" style={{width:'100%'}}/> ???
Tengo bastantes dudas al respecto

Comment: `obj` sería lo que retorna la api, `data`. Pero no sé cómo guardas esa información, o si no la guardas. Por ello puse un ejemplo genérico.

Comment: La data lo guardo aqui:
const getApi = async () =>{
const data = await fetch('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
const students = await data.json()
setStudents(students.students.map(({grades,...students})=>
({...students,grades,tag:tags,gradedAverage:grades.reduce((acc ,item)=>acc + 1*item,0)/grades.length})))**      
};

El problema es que si sigo tu codigo students.students= students.students.map(...

me tira error de mapeo de indefinidos... no se si tendras alguna respuesta sobre ello

Comment: [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/kfbgqd5x/) te dejo un ejemplo completo, tengo que cambiar bastantes cosas para hacer el ejemplo mas chico, pero la idea estaría. En este caso se guardarían nos students, no el objeto original.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. En consola, funciona todo OK. El problema es cuando ingreso el valor en el input....que deberia cambiar?

<input type="text" placeholder="Add a Tag" onKeyUp={e=>(e.key ==="Enter" ? setTags(e,item.id):null)} />

Comment: Este es el error que me tira al escribir un tag en pantalla y dale enter
https://ibb.co/7nPFbNS

Lo mismo me pasa al escribir en el input de busqueda de tags

<TextField onChange={(e)=>{filtrar_pot_tag(e.target.value)}}  id="standard-search2"  label="Search by tags" type="search" style={{width:'100%'}}/>

Comment: calculo que debe ser por el event.target.value. pero no se como solucionarlo

Comment: No sé, calculo que es porque hay que revisar en qué momentos se hace cada cosa